# jQuery/Javascript css("width") / check if style is defined in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a stylesheet which defines default width for images. When I read the image width style with jQuery `width()` it returns the right width. It also returns the same width when I call `css("width")`. But if there is no width defined in the stylesheet the function `css("width")` will also return the computed `width()` value but won't say `undefined` or `auto` or something like that.

Any ideas how I could find out if style is or is not defined in the CSS code?

Solution works for me cross browser. Thanks to everyone for helping:

```
$(this).addClass("default_width_check");
var width = ($(this).width() == 12345) ? 'none-defined' : $(this).width();
var height = ($(this).height() == 12345) ? 'none-defined' : $(this).height();
$(this).removeClass("default_width_check");

.default_width_check {
    width: 12345;
}
```

Comment: interesting question. i wonder why you need this?

Comment: I think this is behaviour defined in the HTML spec: The width attribute of the element gets set to the actual element width if not specified. Tricky, interested to see whether any solution comes up

Comment: I have an CMS which has strict definitions for image and text size. However, the image size is defined in css for each image in each special template used by the CMS. If the admin rolls over the image i want to show the width and height defined in the css so the user knows how to crop/scale the image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have a workaround idea that *might* work.

Define a class named `default_width` *before all other style sheets*:

```
.default_width { width: 1787px }  
/* An arbitrary value unlikely to be an image's width, but not too large
   in case the browser reserves memory for it */
```

to find out whether an image has a width set:

- Clone it in jQuery: `element = $("#img").clone()`
- give the cloned element the `default_width` class: `element.addClass("default_width")`
- If its width is 1787px, it has no width set - or, of course, is natively 1787px wide, which is the only case in which this method will not work.

I'm not entirely sure whether this will work, but it might. **Edit**: As @bobince points out in the comments, you will need to insert the element into the DOM  for all classes to be applied correctly, in order to make a correct width calculation.

Comment: Hmm... interesting hack! I think you would have to alter the element in-place, though, to make sure that all the same rules apply to it. That's OK, you can `addClass`, measure, and immediately `removeClass` without forcing a redraw. Unfortunately a class selector has higher specificity than an element selector, so if a width was set by an element selector this would override it and decide no width was set. Can't really see any way around this, as there is no `!unimportant` declaration...

Comment: @bobince good point about doing it in place! The higher specificity is a shortcoming, true. Chances are it's not a problem in the case at hand because a `width` won't be set globally for all `img` s but still. I can't see a way around this, though, messing with the `default_width` class (like narrowing it down to match a specific attribute) will only make it *more* specific.

Answer (score 8):

No, the `getComputedStyle()` method on which jQuery's `css()` function depends cannot distinguish between an width computed from `auto` vs explicit widths. You can't tell if there was something set in the stylesheet, only from direct inline `style="width: ..."` (which is reflected in the element's `.style.width` property).

`currentStyle` works differently and will give you `auto`, however this is a non-standard IE extension.

If you *really* wanted to work it out, you could iterate over `document.styleSheets`, reading each of their declarations, getting the selector out and querying it to see whether your target element matched, then seeing if it contains a `width` rule. This would, however, be slow and not at all fun, especially as IE's styleSheet DOM differs from the other browsers. (And it still wouldn't cope with pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes, like `:hover`.)

Comment: +1 - With the jQuery 1.4.3 CSS rewrite this really should have been exposed (bypasses the hooks) to be a bit handier since all the code's there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `image.style.width` (image should be your element). This returns an empty string if it's not defined in CSS.

Comment: I don't think so: This will return an empty string if the `style` property was not set, but it will not recognize a setting set in an arbitrary class in the style sheet. I'm happy to stand corrected but I'm pretty sure about this

Answer (score 0):

You can check the element's style.cssText if the width is defined;

```
<img id="pic" style="width:20px;" src="http://sstatic.net/ads/img/careers-ad-header-so.png" />

var pic = document.getElementById('pic');
alert(pic.style.cssText);
```

​But please note of the following styles

```
border-width: 10px;
width: 10px;
```

you should only match the width not the border-width.

Comment: This won't apply to properties set in classes, though, will it?

Comment: You're right there Pekka! it will not work on width defined on css classes, this will only work inline css.