# Get "set" width of a given element

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div that needs to be given a width. i.e. A width must be manually set, either via CSS or via an inline style (Google Maps requires a set width and I'm trying to implement a fail safe, so to speak. If a developer messes up and fails to specify the width, I'd like to set a default width).

In my JS, I am checking like so:

```
var width = document.getElementById(this.divId).clientWidth;
```

Unfortunately, this is giving me back `1920px`, even though a width has not been set (I understand why this is happening).

Is there a way to check if the width has been manually specified or not?

PS: I would like to do this without the aid of libraries such as JQuery.

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn't just have a default width set in the CSS that is inherited if a developer fails to specify a width?

Comment: @misterManSam I'd like to keep the library as simple as possible. Not a fan of adding stylesheets to the equation. Plus, I've no idea what div ID they'll be using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle).

Ex: `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(this.divId),null).getPropertyValue("width")`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v0gk75dr/)**

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me the same result.

Comment: Can you post the HTML and CSS you're using?

Comment: @WayneWhitty: That should work. Sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/Lksohvoy/).

Comment: @Harry Unfortunately, if you remove one of the styles, it defaults to the width of the parent container. I understand why that is happening - It's just that I will need to know whether it has been manually set or not.

Comment: If you run this: http://jsfiddle.net/v0gk75dr/1/ You'll see that a width is being returned, even though it wasn't set. Maybe I was a bit ambiguous in my question?

Comment: @WayneWhitty: Oh yeah, got you mate. Let me check if there is any way.

Comment: But every visible element has a width, regardless if it was set via CSS or not.

Comment: @j08691 Oh, I understand that. However, this particular use case requires a set width. Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: @WayneWhitty: For inline styles checking, you can use something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/Lksohvoy/1/). But for rules in CSS, it is going to be very difficult because we have to traverse through each rule and the selectors could have any combination (like just id or .class#id or .class #id etc).

Comment: @WayneWhitty: You could probably try something like given in this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105355/jquery-javascript-csswidth-check-if-style-is-defined-in-css) also. Not sure if it is fool proof but sounds good. Ofcourse, that answer uses jQuery but I think we can port it to vanilla JS.

Comment: @Harry Thanks for the help! Looks as though I'm out of luck on this one. Bit wary of implementing any workarounds (or using JQuery) as its for a vanilla JS library that needs to work on multiple browsers. Guess I'm just going to have to hope that the user of said library has manually set the width.

Answer (score 1):

```
var width = document.getElementById(this.divId).getAttribute("width");
```

for getting the width attribute

```
 function getCSS(element, property) {

 var elem = document.getElementById(element);
 var css = null;

 if(elem.currentStyle) {

 css = elem.currentStyle[property];


 } else if(window.getComputedStyle) {


 css = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null).
       getPropertyValue(property);

 }

 return css;



}
```

and this is for getting the css value of width or any other css attribute. you can verify the max or min of width and if it's not in the failsafe range you update with default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOM api [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0gk75dr/3/)

Style:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.width
```

Attribute:

```
document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("width")
```